# Use WrapFig and FigBib at the same time?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

Can I somehow combine the two of them? Or do I have to use `fbFloat`? If so, how to do it in a nice way?

I want to have text around my image just like [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures), but at the same time I want to use `FigBib`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out myself. I have to admit, it's a really stupid question. Instead of using `\fbEpsfig`, I should've used `\fbEps` (or `\fbEpsM`). Just in case anyone has got this problem in the future that's the solution ;-)